# jQuery 'if' not working if using $(this) but works with ids

Tags: jquery

I've got a form with a load of checkboxes and textareas. When a checkbox is checked, the associated textarea appears. This is working fine.

However, I have a call to a database which gets information to populate the textareas with data if a certain query is made. An example of the HTML is as follows:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="changes-trigger" />
  <label for="changes-trigger">Changes</label>
  <textarea id="changes" name="changes" rows="6" cols="40"><?php echo $report['changes']; ?></textarea>
</li>
```

If data is loaded into the textarea, I want the checkbox to be checked and for the textarea to be shown. If I target the textarea specifically using the `id`, I can do as I wish on page load:

```
if($('#changes').val()) {
  $('#changes-trigger').prop('checked','true');
  $('#changes').show();
}
```

However, as I said, I have a load of these and do not want to code for each individual one. 
Not only doesn't this do as I wish, it breaks the rest of my external .js file. Can anyone advise why the following doesn't work?

```
if($('textarea').val()) {
  $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked','true');
  $(this).show();
}
```

Comment: How does the loop looks that wraps your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `each` to iterate through all `textarea`s in this way:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    if($(this).val()) {
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked','true');
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Right, that makes total sense and although everyone's saying the same, you got there first. Wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$('textarea').val()` will reference all 'textarea' elements on your page, try -

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
      $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked','true');
      $(this).show();
    }
})
```

That should loop through all the textboxes on the page and apply your logic to each.

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting `this` to now refer to the set of textareas on the page because you referenced them in your `if`and it won't do that - it won't change inside a function.

You could do

```
$('div#abc textarea').each(function() {
    if($(this).val()) {
        $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked','true');
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

instead. I suggest you search for only textareas inside a given div or similar (here with id abc) and only update inputs of the right type too!

Comment: Right, got it. No need to worry about inputs of different types, they will never exist as a sibling of the textareas but I get your point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` context points to the `window` object unless it has been changed by an event callback or by using `.call` or `.apply`.

Instead, use this:

```
var $textarea = $('textarea');
if($textarea.val()) {
  $textarea.siblings('input').prop('checked','true');
  $textarea.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `TEXTAREA` selector will return you an array of all the textarea on your page. Applying `.val()` to this will only return you the value of the first textarea in the DOM tree. Fiddle to prove: http://jsfiddle.net/sc4vc/

You need to use the `.each()` method to get the specific value of each `textarea`

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked','true');
        $(this).show(); 
    }
}
```